# Access S3 bucket from VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm running a NodeJS script and using the aws-sdk package to write files to an S3 bucket. This works fine when I run the script locally, but not from a ECS Fargate service, that's when I get `Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied`.

The service has the allowed VPC `vpc-05dd973c0e64f7dbc`. I've tried adding an Internet Gateway to this VPC, and also an endpoint (as seen in the attached image) - but nothing resolves the Access Denied error. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

**SOLVED:** the problem was me misunderstanding aws:sourceVpce. It requires the VPC endpoint id and not the VPC id. **

**Endpoint**

[image: Endpoint]

**Internet Gateway**
[image: Internet Gateway]

**Bucket policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3MKW5OAU5CHLI"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1582486025157",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpc-05dd973c0e64f7dbc"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your IAM role has cloudfront as. the Principal - for fargate, shouldn't this be ECS?

Comment: `Access Denied` comes from the destination service (in this case, Amazon S3). It means that the network connectivity is fine, but the service is rejecting your request.

Comment: Your bucket policy is only permitting access from CloudFront if the VPC is the one specified. These two requirements are contradictory, so the policy will not grant access. If you wish to grant access to CloudFront _OR_ from a VPC, you will need to create two separate Statements.

Comment: I've updated the bucket policy with what I believe should be a working definition, but I'm still seeing Access Denied. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add an bucket policy that allows access from the VPC endpoint.

Update your bucket policy with a condition, that allows users to access the S3 bucket when the request is from the VPC endpoint that you created. To white list those users to download objects, you can use a bucket policy that's similar to the following:

Note: For the value of `aws:sourceVpce`, enter the VPC endpoint ID of the endpoint that you created.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1314555909999",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "<<Access-to-specific-VPConly>>",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
           "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1c2g3t4e"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I've updated the bucket policy with what I believe should be a working definition, but I'm still seeing Access Denied. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Try "Principal" : "*" in bucket policy, also you need to add s3:ListBucket permission to be able to list the bucket.   ListBucket permission needs to be add as a separate statement in the policy.

Comment: The problem was me misunderstanding aws:sourceVpce. It requires the VPC endpoint id and not the VPC id. Changing that made it work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i mentioned in my 2 note here same.

Comment: Good luck. Mark this as an answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: Having similar issues with dynamoDB your comments helped thank you.